# Android EasyPusher JNI error, solve or disable?

Tags: android

I am using EasyPusher to stream camera through RTSP. The app is working with no any issue, but in the Logcat, it keeps printing this error `easypusher_jni: ____isActivated__....... userPtr=-1195202048` during streaming. Is it a way to resolve the error, or how to just disable the error as the app is working fine.

Comment: It does not look like there is source available for the JNI components, so you will have to reverse engineer the binary and stub out the call.

Comment: Is there a way to disable the printout?

Comment: Unless documentation provides you with another way, you're stuck with editing the binary or asking the authors.